# Vector field commutator in terms of flow

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-derivative

Let $X, Y$ be smooth vector fields on $M$, and $\phi_t$ the flow of X, i.e. the map

\begin{align}
\phi_t = \phi( \cdot \;, t): M \rightarrow M
\end{align}

defined by the integral curves $\gamma_p$ of $X$ for $p\in M$ by

\begin{align}
\phi: M \times \mathbb{R} &\rightarrow M\\
(p, t) &\rightarrow \gamma_p(t)
\end{align}

such that

\begin{align}
\gamma_p(0) = p, \qquad \dot{\gamma}_p(t) = X_{\gamma_p(t)}.
\end{align}

I am trying to prove that the vector field commutator at a point $p$ is given by

\begin{align}
[X, Y]_p = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(\phi_{-t})_*Y_{\phi_t(p)}.
\end{align}

Firstly, from the definitions above, $\phi_t(p) = \gamma_p(t)$. Using the definition of the pushforward, we have

\begin{align}
(\phi_{-t})_*Y_{\phi_t(p)} = (D_{\phi_t(p)}\phi_{-t})(Y_{\phi_t(p)}).
\end{align}

Now let $Y_{\phi_t(p)} = \dot{\sigma}(o)$ for some curve $\sigma$ on $M$, and note that the point $\sigma(0) = \gamma_p(t)$. Then

\begin{align}
(\phi_{-t})_*Y_{\phi_t(p)} &= (D_{\phi_t(p)}\phi_{-t})(Y_{\phi_t(p)}) \\
& = (D_{\phi_t(p)}\phi_{-t})(\dot{\sigma}(o)) \\
& = (\dot{\phi_{-t} \circ \sigma})(0) \\
& = (\dot{\phi}_{-t}(\sigma(0))(\dot{\sigma}(o)) \\
& = (\dot{\phi}_{-t}(\phi_t(p))(Y_{\phi_t(p)}) \\
& = (\dot{\phi}_{-t}(\gamma_p(t))(Y_{\gamma_p(t)})
\end{align}

At this point, I get stuck and I'm not sure where to go. In the end, I'm expecting to get something of the form $X_p(Y_pf) - Y_p(X_pf)$, where $f$ is some arbitrary function, but I don't know how to proceed further with the derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in coordinates, this is a straightforward computation using the chain rule:

Working in coordinates, we have
$$(\phi_{-t})_*Y(\phi_t(x)) = D\phi_{-t}(\phi_t(x))Y(\phi_t(x)) = D_x\phi(-t, \phi(t, x))Y(\phi(t, x)).$$
Now take the $t$ derivative using the product rule and chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left(D_x\phi(-t, \phi(t, x))Y(\phi(t, x))\right) = (-D_{xt}\phi(-t, \phi(t, x)) + D_{xx}\phi(-t, \phi(t, x))D_t\phi(t, x))Y(\phi(t, x)) + D_x\phi(-t, \phi(t, x))DY(\phi(t, x))D_t\phi(t, x).$$
Now set $t = 0$ to get that this equals
$$-D_{xt}\phi(0, x)Y(x) + D_{xx}\phi(0, x)D_t\phi(0, x)Y(x) + D_x\phi(0, x)DY(x)D_t\phi(0, x).$$
We have $D_t\phi(0, x) = X(x)$, so $D_{xt}\phi(0, x) = DX(x)$. Also $D_x\phi(0, x) = I$, so $D_{xx}\phi(0, x) = 0$. So the desired quantity equals
$$-DX(x)Y(x) + DY(x)X(x).$$
This is the coordinate formula for $[X, Y](x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please clarify a few points about the notation and derivatives? In your first line, $D$ acts on a diffeomorphism $\phi_{-t}$, and then you re-write it as $D_x$ acting on the map $\phi(t, x)$ - what is meant by $D_x$? In your second equation, could you be a bit more explicit about the interchange between the total derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$ and $D$ as well?

Comment: @Bedge I use $D$ for Frechet derivative (essentially the Jacobian matrix): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative $D_x$ means the partial Frechet derivative with respect to $x$. $D_t$ means the partial Frechet derivative with respect to $t$. I use $D_{xt} = D_xD_t$. We have $D_xD_t = D_tD_x$ on smooth functions. I never interchange $\frac{d}{dt}$ and $D$ though.

Comment: I have thought a bit more, does the negative sign in the first term come from the chain rule w.r.t. the first argument as $\frac{d}{dt}D_x\phi(-t, \phi(t, x)) = D_{tx}\phi(-t, \phi(t, x))\frac{d (-t)}{d t} + \text{ other term}$?

Comment: @Bedge Correct.